# MySQL search enquiry error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a form which allows the user to search for an event using the Venue and category fields which are scripted as dropdown boxes and the Price and finally by event title, as shown via the code if a keyword is entered which matches the fields on the database it should output all the related information for that event if any matches have been made on either search fields, but it seems to output every single event from the database no matter what I type in the search field.

DATABASE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8k4V6.jpg

HTML FORM

```
    <form name="searchform" action ="PHP/searchfunction.php" method = "post" >
<h2>Event Search:</h2>
Use the Check Boxes to indicate which fields you watch to search with
<br /><br />
<h2>Search by Venue:</h2>

<?php
echo "<select name = 'venueName'>";
$queryresult2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die (mysql_error());
while   ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult2))  {
echo "\n";
$venueID = $row['venueID'];
$venueName = $row['venueName'];
echo "<option value = '$venueID'";
echo ">$venueName</option>";
}# when the option selected matches the queryresult it will echo this

echo "</select>";
mysql_free_result($queryresult2);
mysql_close($conn);
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="S_venueName">
<br /><br />
<h2>Search by Category:</h2>
<?php
include 'PHP/database_conn.php';

$sql3 ="SELECT catID, catDesc
FROM te_category";

echo "<select name = 'catdesc'>";
$queryresult3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die (mysql_error());
while   ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult3))  {
echo "\n";
$catID = $row['catID'];
$catDesc = $row['catDesc'];
echo "<option value = '$catID'";
echo ">$catDesc </option>";
}

echo "</select>";
mysql_free_result($queryresult3);
mysql_close($conn);
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="S_catDes">
<br /><br />

<h2>Search By Price</h2>
<input type="text" name="S_price" />
<input type="checkbox" name="S_CheckPrice">
<br /><br />

<h2>Search By Event title</h2>
<input type="text" name="S_EventT" />
<input type="checkbox" name="S_EventTitle">
<br /><br />
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Search">
```

searchfunction.php file

```
<?php
$count = 0;
include 'database_conn.php';


$venuename = $_REQUEST['venueName']; //this is an integer
$catdesc = $_REQUEST['catdesc']; //this is a string
$Price = $_REQUEST['S_price'];
$EventT = $_REQUEST['S_EventT'];



$sql = "select * FROM te_events WHERE venueID LIKE '%$venuename%' OR catID LIKE '%$catdesc%' OR          eventPrice LIKE '%Price%' OR eventTitle LIKE '%$EventT%'";

$queryresult = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryresult))
{
    echo $row['eventTitle'];
    echo $row['eventDescription'];
    echo $row['venueID'];
    echo $row['catID'];
    echo $row['eventStartDate'];
    echo $row['eventEndDate'];
    echo $row['eventPrice'];
}

mysql_free_result($queryresult);
mysql_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: SQL query in `$sql2` is not included in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query should be
$sql = "select * FROM te_events 
WHERE (venueID LIKE '%$venuename%' 
OR catID LIKE '%$catdesc%'
OR eventPrice LIKE '%$Price%' 
OR eventTitle LIKE '%$EventT%')
;

Comment: And what about SQL injection?

Comment: Yes you are right. to avoid SQL injection we can use mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: __NO.__ Read the contents of red box in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php Robust DB APIs use parametrized queries for this purpose - example is in http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php This kind of code is cleaner and easier to maintain. MySQL extension is deprecated and MySQLi should be used.

Comment: You are awesome Sir. This is the best way to use. +1 for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are matching on any fields surrounded by wildcards, if any of the fields are blank, then the MySQL query will match all rows.

Also, you need to prevent MySQL injection.  Otherwise, your MySQL table will eventually be hacked.

By the way, the code `eventPrice LIKE '%Price%'` is invalid and is missing a dollar sign.

Lastly, the `mysql` extension has been deprecated.  I would recommend using `mysqli` instead as it is fairly similar.

Comment: I agree with the first sentence. But when you prevent SQL injection by using parametrized prepared queries, there is no point in fixing typo as you suggest in the second sentence. Using this PHP feature (to easily put variable value into string) for building SQL query is __completely wrong.__

Answer (score 0):

To get values from the form submitted with method `POST` we use `$_POST` to access form data and not `$_REQUEST`:

```
$venuename = $_POST['venueName']; //this is an integer
$catdesc = $_POST['catdesc']; //this is a string
$Price = $_POST['S_price'];
$EventT = $_POST['S_EventT'];
```

That was about your problem - now some important notes:
Do not use `mysql` extension as it's deprecated. Read [this official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php).
Use `mysqli` and prevent SQL injections by using prepared queries and parameters like in [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) again.

Comment: ok, I have made those changes, I will have to tidy the output of the results to see if that has fixed it.